# Для чего computer science?

Tags: книги, информатика

Для чего нужен computer science программисту? Какую литературу изучить по ней?

Answer (score 1):

Русская Википедия переводит **Computer Science** как [Информатика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). То есть это просто обозначение более общей области знаний, включающее в себя программирование. Если вкратце, то программисту хорошо бы изучить алгоритмы и структуры данных, книг много на эту тему, я бы порекомендовал те книги, где это всё привязано к конкретному языку программирования, который вы знаете.